# Android equivalent of IBActions and IBOutlets

Tags: iphone, android

I am thinking of starting with android development.

What are the equivalents of IBActions and IBOutlets in android?

Is it as easy as Interface Builder to setup connections to code?

Is it quick to learn the basics of android development if one knows java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your last question, I'd answer "yes".

You still wire up the interface to your code but currently you do this programmatically and on the fly: After giving a view an id by `<Button android:id="@+id/myButton" />` or some such in your XML layout file you then call, in your code and after the layout has been created, `View myButton = findViewById(R.layout.myButton)`. The latter is the equivalent of an `IBOutlet` and wiring it in IB except the connection is made when you need it. (You could also do this programmatically for the iPhone if you wanted.)

The equivalent of an IBAction is to use `onClickListener`, declaring `myButton.setOnClickListener(this);` and that `this` implements View.OnClickListener. You then override `public void onClick(View v)` and use a switch on `v.id`.

In practice this is all not as bad as I've made it sound. The major pain with developing for Android that I encounter is scaling the views for different devices.

If you grasp this and intents, the rest is pretty much plain ol' Java.

Comment: "The major pain with developing for Android that I encounter is scaling the views for different devices." - That sounds like a major pain.

Comment: @alJaree: A second major pain I'm coming to terms with is the limit on file sizes in the APK. Files that are larger than 1MB uncompressed are not read, and it's actually an error to put these in certain folders (such as "assets"). No such worries on the iPhone, where large SQLite databases are always made very welcome.

Comment: From my own experience, the simulator was enough to push me in the iphone direction and I havent had any major problems with iOS.

Comment: @alJaree: Well I can relate to that, that's my experience too. I keep dipping my toe with Android and then finding something that jars and pushes me back to iPhone. However it is getting easier and I will say that it's well worth iPhone developers persevering with the Android. I find the Android docs not to the same level as the Apple developer docs but there are still plenty of examples in the Android docs and elsewhere and that helps me a lot. If you've developed for the iPhone you already know what questions to ask on Android.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's far, far (*really* far) *easier* to connect code to UI elements in Android than it is in Xcode/IB.  However, it's all a matter of what you're accustomed to.  I come from the Microsoft ecosystem, where the integration between code and UI designer has been seamless and effortless for the last 15 years (starting with Visual Basic through the latest versions of Visual Studio).  Android development (in Eclipse at least) is much more like the MS world than the Xcode/IB world, although there isn't really a designer like in Visual Studio.

To get started with Android, it's probably best to just discard most of the iPhone concepts that you're used to, rather than looking for one-to-one analogs.  I'm currently in the process of learning iPhone development, and I'm finding it best to just accept how things are done there rather than assuming it's just like C#/.Net with different names for everything.

Comment: I started looking into android a while back and found the simulator to be tedious and annoying, spiking cpu etc. So I went for iphone. I am just wondering if it worth learning android to the point that my iphone and android skills are equal or if it would be wiser to forward my iphone development with e.g. opengl es? Big decision. :P

Comment: @alJaree: the Android simulator is a complete disaster - you definitely need an actual device to develop on. My personal opinion of the iPhone is that Apple is all about marketing overpriced devices to a self-perceived elite, which means it's just not fundamentally possible for them to dominate in terms of market share. So Android is already beating them and heading upwards, and Windows Phone 7 will eventually surpass them as well. If you want to develop skills for the biggest possible market, go Android.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: That is true. My question is how will games written in c++ and objective C compare to Java based android games? Surely games for iphone will out do android based on the frameworks and power of C variants? Or am I wrong? I am not against android, it does feel that everyone is bashing the iphone because they are ahead. There are always articles about why android is now as good as iphone or better than iphone as if it has something to prove.

Comment: All the platforms have devices that are roughly comparable in terms of processor power, memory, screens etc. (except for Blackberry, which is at roughly a 2005 level of technology). And all of the OSes have roughly comparable capability - none has any sort of dominant edge other than length of time in the market (which iPhone wins hands down, obviously).

Comment: This might be interesting if you havent read about it already. http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/05/13/apple_exploring_interactive_glasses_free_3d_holographic_displays.html

Comment: That's definitely interesting, although I suspect that's not going to be in iPhone 4.5. :-)

Comment: hehe. no :P I guess they will make desktop/laptop displays touch screens along with holograms and 3d displays.

Answer (score 1):

There are no IBOutlets, IBActions in neither in AndroidDev eco nor in Visual Studio  eco.

Instead of IBOUtlet, you have to find the control and cast it to proper type.

```
Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.but1)
```

IBAction could be done in 2 different ways

Pure code >>

```
//find Button b1 = ...
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              //do something
          }
       });
```

or with Layouts >>

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:onClick="button2Clicked"
    android:text="@string/text_but_1" />
```

xCode does exactlly the same thing actually.
ibOutlets and ibActions are just synthetic sugar.
the same stuff goes on while touch classes are read and initiated from storyboard xml

Visual Studio too uses synthetic sugar like xCode.
When you double click a button , the code you will write manually in Android Developer are automatically written in a file called className.config.cs

i am a newbie in androidStudio. Couldn't find that design interface synthetic sugar like in xCode and VisualStudio. Maybe there is but i just couldn't find it.

Android Developer and Visual Studio code completence is nothing like xCode.
xCode sucks in those areas. I use them all.
When you see a quetation mark just left side of the code , click it.
or just hit Alt+Enter.

AndDev will write lots of code for you

c# and java developers are very used to call methods which are not yet written, read variables that do not exist.

Remember Alt+Enter !  AndDev will do it all for you